# How to change table view cell height at runtime while using tableViews self sizing cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have main tableView **M** which has **X** number of cells, each **x** has sub tableView **S** with **N** number of cells.
I use **estimatedRowHeight** and **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** to create dynamic cells **height**.
The question is, how to force the **M** table view to relayout and change the height of **x** cells to fit the content size of the **S** tableView at runtime?

[here is an image of what i want to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvEjy.png)

Comment: Are you using UITableViewAutomaticDimension for tableView M?

Comment: yeah, and also for the tableView S

Comment: Are the cells in both of your table views completely (and properly) "linked" with constraints to allow auto layout to size the cells for you? Did you give `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` for both tables a substantial number and not just `1`?

Comment: @Mia
yeah, the problem is when I try to change the height constraints of the S tableView .. I need the X cell to adapt with the new height of S at runtime.

Comment: If the constraints are all seamlessly chained together (top-most subview to to of the cell, bottom-most to bottom of the cell, without constants), runtime changes shouldn't be a problem at all when you call `layoutIfNeeded()` to update the constraint changes. Can you post your basic setup?

Comment: @Mia 
I tried layoutIfNeeded .. it didn't solve my problem because the tableView S Height constraints changes but the X cell height didn't change.
look at to the image in the description of my post.

Comment: I meant post your code so we can see how you have it setup.

Comment: @Mia
TableView M: https://gist.github.com/YoussefMostafa/fcf8af4f16a31404d53d21d28246b20e
Cell X: 
https://gist.github.com/YoussefMostafa/7f253e6b0dd791ee0a8e566021f48cd4

Cell N:
https://gist.github.com/YoussefMostafa/ac6ffd5e05204bfc06d6eddfa39aeb54

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to manually calculate the height of each cell(each X cell) in table view M. First find the height of your tableView S's height in each X cell.

**Calculating TableView S's height:**

Height = Number of cells * Height of each cell(N)

X cell's height = Height

NOTE: Here you'd mentioned that you are using UITableViewAutomaticDimension for tableView S also. So you ned to find the height of the each cell N, based on your content in it. E,g: If you are gonna to load string in cell N, just calculate label height based on string length and then provide your Cell N height by adding proper spacing height with label height.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate it manually height of each cell in table view M. before that find out the height of your tableView S's height with N cells.

1. get S's tableview.contentSize.height
2. give this contentSize to the M's cell X.
3. now get M's tableview.contentSize.height

make two individual methods for getting tableview's height by their cells and write them in "cellAtRow" delegate of tableview. (make iboutlet of  height constraint of auto layout). just reload table when it need to change at run time.